# Set Max available product quantity on add to cart if user adds more in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I have issue an about quantity of product in woocommerce.
I would like to Add total quantity to cart if user enter more than the remaining Quantity for a product.

I have tried a lot of different snippet codes for this, but all in vain.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_add_to_cart`**, that will set the maximum available product quantity in cart, when customer adds more than the remaining available product quantity:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart_qty', 10, 6 );
function add_to_cart_qty( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ){

    $real_product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;

    $product = wc_get_product($real_product_id);
    $product_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    // Zero or negative stock (remove the product)
    if( $product_stock <= 0 && $product->get_manage_stock() ){
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
        return;
    }

    if( $quantity > $product_stock && $product->get_manage_stock() ){
        WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $product_stock );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme) or in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works even for product variations.

Comment: thanks for your concern, I have pasted this code into functions.php file but nothing happened. my shop page URL is this. http://dev14.explorelogics.com/shop can you plz recheck it.?

Comment: i have pasted it again but still the error same. you can check this screenshot http://icecream.me/5d58168f3f9067d9e12620431087538a
i have checked for both simple and variable product but nothing happened. :(

Comment: thanks for your effort but there is one error when I enable backorders then quantity can go more than stock, e.g the stock is 12 items for the first time when we enter 20 items then only 12 items add in cart but for the next time when i again go to this product and enter quantity 5 or more, then again this quantity goes to cart, in this way quantity goes in cart more than stock, this is the issue.
i will must mark this question as complete as i got my solution.
thanks again for your time.

Comment: and stock quantity goes in minus. you can check this
http://icecream.me/d2a93ad5b5ec094f3c11347638f60856

Comment: Because the first time when you add the quantity, you need to make an order and this order need a "completed" status to reduce the product stock quantity… Now I haven't think about negative stock value… so I make an update for that…

Comment: thanks @LoicTheAztec, i have tried it again but the issue is same for the second time add to cart, user can change their quantity at any time, we can't restrict the user for just once enter quantity, user can modify quantity at any time before place the order, and in this way stock goes below the zero

Comment: @MuhammadBilal Yes of course, but this is another question… My code is maid just when adding to cart, as you asked in your question… So you will need to make a new question related to change quantities in cart page. You can use my code here in your new question, It will avoid downvotes normally.